# Tomcat server's memory leaking after a lot of redeployment

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, war

I noticed that after a lot of redeployment of .war (using 'scp' command line) on my tomcat production server, the latter seems to start a memory leak. How can I do to put this tomcat server in an always clean state before deploying a new .war each time ?

Comment: Which version of tomcat do you use?

Comment: My version is the 7.0

Comment: @user3793589 Did you find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. An acceptable way to make sure it doesn't happen anymore was to uninstall and reinstall tomcat before each redeployment... :-(

Comment: the same issue here...